# Display content only in selected regions with IP

Tags: php, ip

Is it possible to show a special web page content only to the US? Can I do that with the IP of the visitor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, you can. Please try it like below:

```
<?php

$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$result = file_get_contents( "http://echoip.ir/" . $ip );

if ( $result ) {

    $result_decode = json_decode( $result, true );

    if ( $result_decode['ip2location']['country_short'] == "US" ) {

      // Show your page

    }

}

?>
```

Comment: Thanks, but how does this work? I just want to understand the code.

Comment: First, I'll get information ( Like country, city, local time and ...) from API by user IP. Then I'll check the country user by "US", if matched, you can show your page...

Comment: And the lookup which IP routes to which country is done at that page http://echoip.ir/?

Comment: Every website that provide API for IPs, have a database, for example in this website: https://www.ip2location.com/ users can purchase database of IP with Geo location.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that, thats awsome, is it possible to add two or more countries to the if statment? and what country code is used? And is this limited on some requests per month?

Comment: Of course, for example: `if ( in_array( $result_decode['ip2location']['country_short'], array( "US", "CA" ) ) )` . that's use standard country code ( you can find in : http://www.mokhafaf.com/en/country/ )

Comment: Thanks and this is not limited on a request per month?

Comment: You're welcome, hmmmm, usually API services have a limit for users, I don't know limit of echoip.ir :)

Answer (score 0):

You can look for an API which translates IP addresses in locations/areas and then use such data to filter your visitors.

There is no way to read an IP and determine their location based on that.

Example(s):
https://geoipify.whoisxmlapi.com/api
https://ip2loc.com/?gclid=CjwKCAjwldHsBRAoEiwAd0JybSNyxMapSYTA-twwHjVEwBjP3TC2wGojiJ292Yx7RWm3wIn7GdAtMxoCsgoQAvD_BwE

Comment: Do you have an example API?